# Read connection String Data source, User ID and Password and add the values to the variables in NSIS

Tags: textbox, nsis

I am trying to read connection string from web.config file and put those values in a textbox using nsis.

I have three variables

```
var WebConnectionString
Var WebUserID
Var WebPassword
```

I just need to read Data Source, User ID, Password and add those values to the variables.

Could some one please help me with this.

I am able to read these connectionstrings using Powershell and put those values in a text file. When I tried to read values in the text file and put them in the Variables using read value by line number.

I need this values to execute SQL script. When I tried to execute

```
ExecWait `"$TEMP\UpdateSQL.bat" "$WebConnectionString" "$WebUserID" "$WebPassword" "$TEMP\upgrade.sql"
```

The `ExecWait` command is taking the parameters as

```
Execute: "C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Local\Temp\UpdateSQL.bat" 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\' '(local)\SQLExpress' 'User' 'admin123!'
```

here is the config file:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SQLConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=VitalSigns;User ID=User;Password=admin123!;Persist Security Info=True;multipleactiveresultsets=true; Min Pool Size=20;Max Pool Size=500; Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: How are we supposed to know the format of this config file? Maybe you could post some example code of things you have tried so far...

Comment: Sorry, It was supposed to be there in the question itself.

here is the config file:
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SQLConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=VitalSigns;User ID=User;Password=admin123!;Persist Security Info=True;multipleactiveresultsets=true; Min Pool Size=20;Max Pool Size=500; Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

There are [multiple](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/XML_plug-in) NSIS [XML](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisXML_plug-in_(by_Wizou)) [plugins](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisXML_plug-in_(by_Joel)) you can use to read XML files.